# What is the `docker stack deploy` configuration merge behaviour for lists?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Docker allows for multiple compose files

```
docker stack deploy -c base.yml -c env-specific.yml stack_name
```

Given a base.yml as

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  portal:
    image: myimage
    networks:
    - traefik
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 15s
      update_config:
        order: start-first
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https,http"
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
        - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.insecureSkipVerify=true"
        - "traefik.port=8443"
        - "traefik.protocol=https"
```

And a `env-specific.yml` as

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  portal:
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          memory: 256M
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-server.com"
```

What would the resulting merge be? (specifically for the `labels`)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy): To set labels on containers, use the labels key outside of deploy. Otherwise, labels are only set on the service. So I'm guessing the labels are only set for that service when multiple compose files are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the merged config for swarm stacks should be identical to what `docker-compose config` renders:

```
docker-compose -f base.yml -f env-specific.yml config
WARNING: Some services (portal) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
services:
  portal:
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.docker.network: traefik
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.frontend.entryPoints: https,http
        traefik.frontend.insecureSkipVerify: "true"
        traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "true"
        traefik.frontend.rule: Host:my-server.com
        traefik.port: '8443'
        traefik.protocol: https
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 15s
      update_config:
        order: start-first
    image: myimage
    networks:
      traefik: {}
version: '3.7'
```

Deploy the stack and inspect the service {stack_name}_portal:
`docker service inspect {stack_name}_portal --format '{{range $key, $value := .Spec.Labels}}{{$key}}: {{println $value}}{{end}}'`. The output should list the merged service labels.

In case the rendered config does handle the merge differently, I would suggest to raise an issue in Docker's Github project.